# Acces a vector declared in another else statement

Tags: c++

I have a if/else if statement which depend on an op code, the first option creates a vector, while the second one modifies it, so I decided to define the structure I would use for the vector and declare it inside the first statement, however this option does not allow me to modify it from anywhere else, is there a way to use change some values inside the vector form the second option having it declard in the first one?

```
if(op == "new"){
    cin >> size;
    vec<int> v(size);
} else if(op == "mod"){
    int pos, val;
    cin >> pos >> val;
    v[pos] = val;
}
```

Comment: You cannot do that. This looks like [The XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). What do you acutually want to do?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot acces the vector outside of its scope. Move it up so it is accesible in both branches. Assuming it has a default constructor:

```
vec<int> v;
if(op == "new"){
    cin >> size;
    // resize it or assign a new one to v
} else if(op == "mod"){
    int pos, val;
    cin >> pos >> val;
    v[pos] = val;
}
```

If this is actually `std::vector<int>` consider to `resevere` instead of `resize` and `push_back` instead of accessing elements. In some sense you are wasting the vectors capabilities when you resize it upfront with a number of elements that you don't know if you actually need them.

For a sparse vector (you seem to add `val` at random `pos`), consider to use a `std::unordered_map<size_t,int>` instead.